# UWP sample of app with scattered images

Tags: uwp

I'm looking for a sample app in UWP. The sample app showed pictures scattered all over the screen like thrown on a table. You could move them around, rotate them and resize them. Anyone who knows where to find that sample app ? Or has that code ?

A bit like the orginal surface was behaving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The sample app showed pictures scattered all over the screen like thrown on a table. You could move them around, rotate them and resize them.

I have found the similar code sample via your description. Please refer [Carousel XAML Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/controls/carousel).

> The Carousel control provides a new control, inherited from the ItemsControl, representing a nice and smooth carousel.
>   This control lets you specify a lot of properties for a flexible layouting.
>   The Carousel control works fine with mouse, touch, mouse and keyboard as well.

Comment: It is not exactly what I was looking for, but It will be a great help.